# Can't get TV show name to display

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, data-synchronization, video

I imported a set of .mov files as a TV show, or at least I tried to.

I imported them into iTunes, set them to the same "Show" name, numbered them as season 1, episodes 1-6. I also named them "Episode One", "Episode Two", etc. I also marked them as "Media kind: TV Show".

Everything looks fine in iTunes. The problem is when I sync them to my iPhone, when I look in Videos, under TV Shows, it shows "Episode One" as the name of the show.

So for example, on my iPhone, under TV shows I might see: *Breaking Bad* (4 episodes), *Mad Men* (2 episodes), *House* (3 episodes), *Episode One* (6 episodes).

How can I make the iPhone display the show name? Both "Show" and "Sort Show" are set, but the iPhone seems to be ignoring them...

Comment: ERJ - If you're up for experimenting you could duplicate one episode and place different dummy information in each fields that iTunes provides. Then you can figure what fields your phone displays.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to check the following fields - they are the ones I see on iOS 6 when I sync a TV show to my iPhone:

- Video tab: Show and Season Number
- Info tab: Name and Album

The information from the first item (Video tab) is shown in the top level view of the Videos app and the second line (Info tab) gets shown when you drill down to see the episodes that have synced over to the phone. If you sync to an iPad, more details are shown in the video app - but the core 4 items above are shown there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, today on an iPhone 6 with latest iTunes (Windows) + iOS versions. Three series of Breaking Bad: all titles, series + episode numbers entered correctly and showing up fine in iTunes. After sync, all were viewable on the phone but nowhere did 'Breaking Bad' show up as a name. To fix it, all I did was 'Get Info' individually for each series 1 episode and typed in 'Breaking Bad' under 'grouping'. After the sync, all episodes of all three series showed up correctly, including the series 2 and 3 episodes which I didn't even edit.

Answer (score -1):

i had exactly the same problem. i put the show name in under "director" and synched again and voila they are now in a named folder. but that may have been just because i synched it a 2nd time.